# How can I make a thread in bluesky social?

Tags: node.js, openai-api

I'm trying to make a thread automatically using 'reply' in bliesky social. (To crwal my blog)
But this code just makes new posts everytime.
I think the problem is this code can't get 'treadID'.
How can I correct it?

```
async function postToBluesky(url, text) {
  try {
    const summaryText = await summarizeText(text); // get summary as string
    const rt = new RichText({ text: summaryText }); // pass summary as string

    // Divide the text into parts of 250 characters
    const parts = [];
    while (text.length > 0) {
      parts.push(text.substring(0, 250));
      text = text.substring(250);
    }

    // Post the first part as a new post
    const postRt = new RichText({ text: parts[0] });
    const postRecord = {
      $type: 'app.bsky.feed.post',
      text: postRt.text,
      user: agent.session.userId,
      facets: [
        {
          name: 'url',
          value: url,
          index: {
            value: 0,
            byteStart: 0,
            byteEnd: postRt.text.length,
          },
          features: [], // Add empty array as features
        },
      ],
      createdAt: new Date().toISOString(),
    };

    const post = await agent.post(postRecord);
    const threadId = post.id; // Set `threadId` to the ID of the new post

    // Post subsequent parts as replies in a thread
    let prevPost = post;
    for (let i = 1; i < parts.length; i++) {
      const replyRt = new RichText({ text: parts[i] });
      const replyRecord = {
```